# Proving either $p$ or $q$

Tags: logic

Proving either $p$ or $q$ means proving we have either '$p$ is true and $q$ is false' or '$p$ is false and $q$ is true'.

So we can do that by excluding the two cases, '$p$ is true and $q$ is true' and '$p$ is false and $q$ is false'.

Is this correct?

Comment: No, both $p$ and $q$ can be true; for example, "$1=1$ or $2=2$" is true.

Comment: Another way to prove $p\lor q$ is to prove $(\lnot p)\to q$.

Comment: @Shaun That is because by proving $(\neg p)\rightarrow q$, we can exclude the case, '$p$ is false and $q$ is false'. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. It can be thought of as *"if not one, then the other"* since, by symmetry, if $(\lnot p)\to q$, then also $(\lnot q)\to p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. "either $p$ or $q$" in everyday mathematical use means

- $p$ true and $q$ false or
- $p$ false and $q$ true or
- $p$ true and $q$ true.

This is called *inclusive or* (symbolically, $\lor$). The reading of "or" where the case where both are true is excluded is called *exclusive or* (often abbreviated "xor") and is not the default meaning of "or".

The truth table for the standard, inclusive "or" looks as follows:

```
p q  p v q 
T T    T   
T F    T   
F T    T   
F F    F
```

1) To prove that the inclusive or is true, prove that

- either $p$ is true, in which case the value of $q$ can be either true (line 1 in the truth table) or false (line 2 in the truth table); or
- $q$ is true, in which case the value of $p$ can be either true (line 1 in the truth table) or false (line 3 in the truth table).

2) To prove that the inclusive or is false, prove that

- $p$ is false and $q$ is false (line 4 in the truth table).

The truth table for the exclusive or looks as follows:

```
p q  p xor q
T T     F
T F     T
F T     T
F F     F
```

3) To prove that the exclusive or is true, prove that

- $p$ is true and $q$ is false (line 2 in the truth table) or
- $p$ is false and $q$ is true (line 3 in the truth table).

4) To prove that the exclusive or is false, prove that

- $p$ is true and $q$ is true (line 1 in the truth table) or
- $p$ is false and $q$ is false (line 4 in the truth table).

Comment: I see. In your answer, 'OR' in the last paragraph, 'To prove the exclusive or, prove that $\cdot$ ... OR $\cdot$ ... ' is used exclusive. Is that right?

Comment: Since not both situations can become true at the same time, the "or" in this situation does in fact become exclusive, yes. But this also is covered by the inclusive meaning of or (inclusive is more general than exclusive: if an exclusive or is true, then the inclusive or is true as well). So in a sense it's both.

Answer (score 2):

Typically "true or true" is considered to be true. If you want to exclude that case then we call it "[XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate)" which is pronounced "exclusive or".

Comment: I see. I am wondering if $p$ XOR $q$ can be proven the above way.

Answer (score 1):

Tidying up lemontree's reply a bit...

**The Truth Table for $p\lor q$**

[image]

To prove $p\lor q$ is true (lines 1-3), do either of the following:

1. Prove $p$ is true.
2. Prove $q$ is true.

To prove $p\lor q$ is false (line 4), prove $p$ is false and $q$ is false.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to state "either $p$ is true, and if p is not true, then $q$ is true, you need to write $$(p\lor q) \land \lnot(p \land q)$$

[image]

This is equivalent to the proposition $$ \lnot (p \iff q).$$

[image]

Else, as has been stated here, $p\lor q$ is true in all cases except when both $p$ and $q$ are both false.

Although in many computing languages, "either $p$ or $q$" means the "exclusive or", as you describe.  But mathematically, and logically, "or" is always taken to be "inclusive": p or q or both p and q, unless otherwise stipulated.